# Syntax error in a Python unit test module

Tags: python

I am trying to use a unit test module called `TestBlbMktData`. PLease see below for the module.  It calls a number of modules via functions to test if they work correctly I have a function definition.  I have  a `SyntaxError : invalid syntax` on line 13:

```
def print(self,data):
```

How can I fix this?

```
import unittest
import os.path
from dao.iotools.blbmktdata import *

class TestBlbMktData(unittest.TestCase):
    staticName='Static.csv'
    reportingName='Reporting.csv'
    corpName='Actions.csv'
    fxName='PER.csv'
    holidayName='Holidays.csv'
    closeDataName='ELB.csv'

    def print(self,data):
        print()
        print(len(data))
        print(data.head())
        print(data.dtypes)

    def read(self,name,func):
        return func(os.path.join(self.current_dir,name))

    def setUp(self):
        self.current_dir=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    def test_corp_act(self):
        self.print(self.read(self.corpName,readCorpAction))

    def test_static(self):
        self.print(self.read(self.staticName,readInstrumentStatic))

    def test_reporting(self):
        self.print(self.read(self.reportingName,readReportingDates))

    def test_fx(self):
        self.print(self.read(self.fxName,readFx))

    def test_holidays(self):
        self.print(self.read(self.holidayName,readHolidays))

    def test_close(self):
        self.print(self.read(self.closeDataName,readClosePrice))
```

The version of Python I am running is 2.7.13.

Comment: can you show the full error message? Also, please try reducing your program to the minimum required to reproduce this problem. Is the library you are using python2 compatible?

Comment: Thanks #Azsgy. I think I fixed it with:  from __future__ import print_function